# 3 monitor layout Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, layout

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my desktop with GeForce 660 GTX. I've been messing around with this problem for some hours now so I'm posting this here.

I'm having 3 monitors here, all connected to card previously mentioned. 2 of the monitors (Samsung 19" and Samsung 22") are connected via DVI and third one, Philips 58" (it's not actually 58", just showing up in the settings like that for some reason) is connected via HDMI-Displayport adapter. There is also Sony amplifier connected via HDMI. All these connected in one card and everything is showing up properly. I've installed nVidia binary driver, version 361.42 from nVidia-361 (proprietary, tested) and everything seems fine with it.

I've used display manager (All settings->Displays) to set layout for these monitors. I can easily set 19" and 22" Samsung monitors side by side, 19" being on the left side and 22" on the right. Now I would like to have this big Philips screen on top of the other screens mentioned before. But I can't manage to get this done.

I'm trying to use display manager and just drag this Philips monitor on top of the others but just can't get it there, for some reason. I can't set it side by side with others either, there is always small gap between monitors. It just wont go there. I would like to have this Philips screen on top of Samsung 22", which is my main screen. So when I would move my mouse through top border of Samsung 22", it would appear through bottom of Philips screen.

I had this similar setup in Windows 8.1 and was working fine and I really hope I can find way to get it working in Ubuntu. Maybe I'm just missing something obvious here.

[image: Screenshot of my monitor setup]

^ Here you can see how my configuration is at the moment; Samsung 19" being on the left, Samsung 22" on the right, then there is this small gap between Samsung 22" and Philips and then there is also Sony amplifier showing on the right (the one with empty desktop, I've no idea why it is also showing up, I can disable it, but then it will affect my sound settings, there won't be no sound at all. Any chance to get rid of it without losing sound?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working, though I'm not quite sure why it worked because I didn't really change anything. Dragging those monitors in display manager seems bit sticky/buggy but finally got monitor layout way I wanted.

Comment: Does it survive a restart? If not, please mention. We can probably fix it then.

Comment: Yes it survives restart just fine. :)

Comment: You can drive any two of: hdmi/dvi/vga, in addition to DP.   Its DP that allows 3+ displays.